# Moved CakePHP app from windows to mac and now one model doesn't load

Tags: cakephp, model

Today I was moving a CakePHP app that I made on windows to my new macbook. For some weird reason one model doesn't load properly. Other models do load properly though, which confuses me...
I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Locale::getLocale() in /server/cakephp/app/Controller/AppController.php on line 59
```

That line is just calling a method in my Locale model that I have.
So I tried to see what $this->Locale looked like with this code:

```
die(pr($this->Locale));
```

And this was the result:

```
Locale Object
(
)
```

I don't know why, but apparently I get an empty object. I tried removing the Locale.php file to see if CakePHP would automatically use AppModel, but it still becomes an empty object. So I tried searching if I have some empty class called Locale somewhere, but I couldn't find it.

Please help, this is so frustrating!

I cloned the CakePHP library from git yesterday, maybe that's useful information? Could it be that Locale has suddenly become a reserved word?

Comment: Check your cases. Don't forget that Windows isn't case sensitive and OS X is CaSe SenSitIvE. Either that, or it's a routing issue. Check your code for anywhere you've hard coded a \ instead of a /. As you should be using the `DS` constant.

Comment: I've always followed the cases conventions and I just double-checked it, they are fine. Also I haven't found a \ anywhere where it should be DS.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions maybe?  I've also had troubles in the past with hidden .files when moving cakephp apps, worth checking.  I'm guessing that git handles both correctly though.